# Как изменить порядок директорий на флешке?

Tags: c#, winapi, fat32

Наверно не для кого не секрет что большинство MP3-плееров не умеет сортировать папки, файлы на флешке и потому очерёдность папок, файлов у них особая.
Насколько я понял эта очерёдность зависит от номера первого кластера куда начинается записываться файл/директория. И самый простой способ разместить папки/файлы в нужном нам порядке это записать эти папки/файлы на флешку в том порядке в каком мы хотим, что бы они воспроизводились.
Я даже написал программу которая таким образом сортирует папки как мне хочеться. Но как мне кажеться это очень топорный способ переписывать директории/файлы туда сюда, да и по времени это затратно если на флешке лежит под сотню папок и около 2000 композиций.
Да, люди уже написали программы которые это делают быстрее, чем переписывание файлов туда-сюда, но хочеться своё, родное.
И как я понял эти програмы как то перенумеровывают первые кластеры (вот тут я уже сильно плаваю в этом вопросе) и соответственно выстраивают такой порядок который необходим.

**Соственно вопрос: как на С# найти эти первые кластеы и директорий и файлов и как их потом перенумеровать что бы выстроился необходимый порядок?**

И да, я уже очень много обыскался в поисках решения этого вопроса, но увы мало что понял, т.к. подавляющее большинство ответов сводится к тому что нужно курить мануалы. Я то не против, но знать бы что мне конкретно нужно? И вроде как C# не очень подходит для этих целей, т.к. нужно подключать функции WinApi и возможно ещё какие то заморочки, но "не очень подходит" не значит что это невозможно.
Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Очередность зависит не от того как файлы физически записаны, а от того как они записаны в файловую систему FAT32. Ваш плеер не умеет в сортировку, поэтому при чтении файловой системы выводит список файлов как есть. Т.к. для прямого доступа к файловой системе нужен низкоуровневый доступ к диску, то на C# это будет проблематично сделать. Первое что нагуглилось: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95721/FAT-32-Sorter - там и описание, и демо, и исходные коды(на плюсах на сколько понял).

Comment: Насчёт очерёдности, как я и сказал, я плаваю в этом вопросе :(. И то что это проблематично реализовать на С# я так же встречал. Но другими словами это же возможно сделать? За ссылку спасибо, я её читал и код смотрел, но увы мало что понял:( Потому и обратился за помощью к коллективному разуму. Так же находил и другую программу с исходниками на Java https://github.com/qxo/NewFAT32Sorter и тоже дупля не отбил как оно работает :( и просто софт по этой теме: http://www.murraymoffatt.com/software-problem-0010.php  В любом случае спасибо что откликнулись.

Comment: Вы уверены, что очередность зависит от порядка записи на физическом носителе, а не от названия файла? У мня, например, были плееры, которые играли файлы именно в алфавитном порядке

Comment: Абсолютно уверен. Наверняка есть плееры которые могут сортировать файлы/директории в алфавитном порядке, но большинство плееров (особенно которые в автомобилях) так делать не умеют и проигрывают файлы в порядке их записи на USB носитель. И потом, мне не нужна какая то ни было сортировка, я хочу расположить файлы так как мне нравиться.